# using props to get value from a table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap

I am trying to build one table using props, and pass the value from that table to another function. But for some reason, the result is not displaying. What have I done wrong?

```
import Table from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-bootstrap@2.5.0";

function Tables(props) {
  
  return (
  <Table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{props.first}</td>
        <td>{props.second}</td>
        <td>{props.third}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </Table>
      )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tables first="Sara" />
      <Tables second="Cahal" />
      <Tables third="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```

Comment: are you sure it's not`<div> <Tables first="Sara" second="Cahal" third="Edite"/></div>` instead of what you now have in `App`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are rendering the table three times, each one with only one prop, you need to

If you want to show one table with the three `props`, it should be like that.

```
import Table from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/react-bootstrap@2.5.0";

function Tables(props) {
  
  return (
  <Table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
        <th>c</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>{props.first}</td>
        <td>{props.second}</td>
        <td>{props.third}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </Table>
      )
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Tables first="Sara" second="Cahal" third="Edite" />
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<App />);
```